Using sqlite3 js to replace html text
So I want to put out a WHERE query for this 'code' (row.code) and recieve the row.title from there.
With the row.title I want to use js to replace the 'title.placeholder' text with 'row.title'. For eg. Jeff becomes Tim as Tim is the title from row.code 003.
This will be to make a system to sort of have dynamic page content on my site.
Cheers for any help,
Tim.
this is my 'grab-replace.js'
"`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
// Open a database connection
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./server/test.db');

// Define your SQL query with a WHERE clause
let sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE code = '003'";

// Initialize a constant variable to store the title
const titlePlaceholder = document.querySelector(".title-placeholder");

// Execute the query
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // Process the retrieved rows
    rows.forEach((row) => {
        // Store the title
        const title = row.title;
        // Update HTML content with the stored title
        if (titlePlaceholder) {
            titlePlaceholder.textContent = title;
        }
    });
});

// Close the database connection when done
db.close();

});`
and this is the html where i reference the script;
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="headerContainer"></div>
    <div class="maintext">>
        <h1 class="title-placeholder">Default Page</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle-placeholder">TEST</h2>
        <h3 class="authorname-placeholder">TEST</h3>
        <h3 class="date-placeholder">02/05/2003</h3>
    <p class="body-placeholder">This is default text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footerContainer"></div>
    
    <script src="/public/js/layout.js"></script>
    <script src="grab-replace.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`

I have had the script.js to work before with replacing the current content of the html with another text eg Title --> 1 but now I have implemented this query it will not work.

I have tried chatgpt now but I firmly believe it has done way more damage then good here.


"I have implemented this query it will not work" ... What about it doesnt work? Any error messages? Have you confirmed the database has opened?

Sorry I should have put more detail. Yes the database is fully functional and opening. The query is working as I have made it print to console. What I think is happening is that when the value for the stored title is saved the db connection then closes and takes the new value with it. No error messages just when i load the hmtl page it does not change the title but all my other js is functioning on the page.

"What I think is happening is that when the value for the stored title is saved the db connection then closes and takes the new value with it" .... Nahhh. Values are not stored to the DOM by reference.

okay so them I am a bit lost for a solution then, thinking about converting over to a php method instead...

Either this rows.forEach((row) => is not iterating rows, or this if (titlePlaceholder) { is always false. You can use console.log("hello world") type statements inside your loop and inside your branches to debug. The messages you put will appear (when things are working up to that point) in the browser's built-in dev tools' console pane.
